# TitanFactory.open(config) : No Locks Available

Tags: titan

I am getting an no lock exception (caused by sleepycat) while trying to open TitanGraph instance below. Any leads what might be causing it ? Am i missing something ? I have checked for permission and ownership of that directory but no luck.

```
TitanGraph titanGraph;
Configuration config = new BaseConfiguration();
Configuration storage = config.subset("storage");
storage.setProperty("backend", "local");
storage.setProperty("directory", "data/titan");
titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(config);
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.instantiate(Backend.java:355)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:367)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:311)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:121)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1163)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:75)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:40)
    at com.narus.tst.graph.GraphDaoImpl.openDb(GraphDaoImpl.java:221)
    at com.narus.tst.job.RunNazca.jobRun(RunNazca.java:267)
    at com.narus.tst.job.RunNazca.runNazca(RunNazca.java:250)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:312)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.instantiate(Backend.java:344)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentStorageException: Error during BerkeleyJE initialization: 
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager.initialize(BerkeleyJEStoreManager.java:74)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager.<init>(BerkeleyJEStoreManager.java:42)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException: (JE 5.0.73) data/titan java.io.IOException: No locks available LOG_INTEGRITY: Log information is incorrect, problem is likely persistent. Environment is invalid and must be closed.
    at com.sleepycat.je.log.FileManager.lockEnvironment(FileManager.java:2181)
    at com.sleepycat.je.log.FileManager.<init>(FileManager.java:370)
    at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.<init>(EnvironmentImpl.java:453)
    at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.<init>(EnvironmentImpl.java:382)
    at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.DbEnvPool.getEnvironment(DbEnvPool.java:178)
    at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.makeEnvironmentImpl(Environment.java:246)
    at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:227)
    at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.<init>(Environment.java:170)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager.initialize(BerkeleyJEStoreManager.java:70)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No locks available
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:90)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1063)
    at com.sleepycat.je.log.FileManager.lockEnvironment(FileManager.java:2171)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: I've never seen that error before, but I think that it points to permission problems (I know you said that you checked that).  I'd consider searching around for that error some more in the context of berkeleydb as I think it is related more to that than titan itself.

Comment: Do you have multiple Titan connections open against BerkeleyDB?

Comment: @JasonPlurad I thought of that too, but you get a slightly different exception for that scenario.  i tested it out and the exception didn't match the one shown here.